Defining EdgeShapeFunction using conditional statements
I want to create a graph with a large number of nodes and customize each of its edges. Since the number of edges is large, I want to define the EdgeShapeFunction using conditional branching rather than manually. I have only found manual customization methods in past Q&A, and I am having trouble with this.
For example, if I want to make certain edges red and the rest blue, ChatGPT suggested the following program, but it was not executable. What should be corrected?
(* Define the graph with nodes and edges *)
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1}];

(* Define the edge shape function with conditional logic for color *)
edgeShapeFunction[edge_, pos_] :=
  If[
    edge == {1, 2} || edge == {2, 1},
    (* Red color for the specific edge *)
    {Red, Line[pos]},
    (* Blue color for other edges *)
    {Blue, Line[pos]}
  ];

(* Plot the graph *)
Graph[g,
  EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeShapeFunction,
  VertexStyle -> Directive[Bold, Blue]
]


You want to change only edge colors? Or, do you really want to change shapes?

Look at the arguments of edgeShapeFunction:
edgeShapeFunction[edge_, pos_] := Print[{edge, pos}]
Graph[g, EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeShapeFunction, 
 VertexStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue]]

You will see that "edge" is a list of coordinates and "pos" is a edge definition. Therefore, you need to swap "edge" and "pos" in your code. Further "Bold" is an option for text, what you want is "Thick". With these changes:
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1}];
edgeShapeFunction[edge_, pos_] := 
  If[pos === DirectedEdge[1, 2], {Red, Line[edge]}, {Blue, 
    Line[edge]}];

Graph[g, EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeShapeFunction, 
 VertexStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue]]



Thank you very much for the reply!!! Now I fully understand why the program created by ChatGpt did not work!!! Based on the program you kindly provided, I will create the edgeshapefunction for my own purpose.

I advise you to use EdgeStyle option rather than defining EdgeShapeFunction.
HighlightGraph[g, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1}]

would be the simplest answer to the original question. But I think that you want to know a method to change edge style for larger graphs. Then, the following example will give some hint. The edge connecting i and j are thick & blue if i and j are coprime to each other, and dotted & red otherwise.
g=CompleteGraph[10,VertexLabels->"Name"];

Graph[g, EdgeStyle -> {i_ \[UndirectedEdge] j_ :> 
If[CoprimeQ[i, j], {Thick, Blue}, {Dotted, Red}]}]



Thank you very much for your prompt response!!! Regarding your clarification, my ultimate goal is to change the shape of specific arrows in a graph. For example, in a certain graph, I want to ensure that a curved arrow from node i to node j avoids overlapping with the label of node k, effectively bypassing it. The method you provided is very useful for specifying EdgeStyle (and possibly EdgeShapeFunction) in a very simple way, and I believe it will be extremely helpful in achieving my own goal!!

I see your ultimate goal. There are no known general method to avoid overlapping --- see for example this question, and people tackle the problem on a case-by-case basis. If you have concrete examples of overlapping graphs, please post as another question.
